# A task was cancelled inner exception while waiting for result from post async method.(Aggregation Exception)

Tags: c#, .net, api, exception, asp.net-web-api

> I am getting this error when i try to execute two queries under one
>   postasync call. I have used parallel for each for executing queries.

Please find image below:[image]

Here is the code of execute async method:

```
  Parallel.ForEach(commands, c =>
            {
                using (ConnectionManager connectionMetaData = new ConnectionManager())
                {
                connectionMetaData.Open(this.settings.ConnectionString);
                AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand(c.Value, connectionMetaData.Connection);
                command.CommandTimeout = timeOut;
                result.Add(c.Key, Cube.ConvertCellSetToDataTable(command.ExecuteCellSet()));
                command.Dispose();
                Thread.Sleep(150);
                }
            });
```

API call code:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.Timeout.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
            HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<dynamic>(Content, jsonFormatter);
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Report + "RequestURI"] + Action, content).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov please find the code Sir !!!!

Comment: You shouldn't call Thread.Sleep(150) and .Result(). Better using async pattern. Make your delegate "c" (inside Parallel.ForEach) async and replace Thead.Sleep(150) by await Task.Delay(150) and replace .Result() by using await. That wouldn't solve your issue but it will be a neater code.

Comment: I bet this has something to do with using `connectionMetaData` across threads. What are the inner exceptions?

Comment: result gets returned from parallel for each though exception occurs.

Comment: inner exception is Task was cancelled